# How to convert RSS HTML to XML in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, rss

I am taking RSS feeds from a website and they are giving me RSS in HTML but I want to convert it to XML using PHP to use it somewhere else as well.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the RSS feed is in XML. Your browser converts it to HTML to show it to you correctly

Comment: This question could be improved by providing a link to the website in question, and also by clarifying what you mean by "they are giving me rss in html".

Comment: @HoLyVieR: HTML and XML have a common ancestor, but they are otherwise very different. That's dangerous information you're distributing, and it gets lots of people into trouble every day.

Comment: @HoLyVieR It's not, actually. XML requires well-formedness and the xmlns, which as of html5 I don't see many people including.

Comment: unless the incoming html is formatted in XHTML (XML formatted HTML, preferrably the strict type). otherwise it's a no go.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an RSS feed in HTML. RSS is defined in an XML format, so anything you see is your browser rendering it in human-readable form.

You can use any of the PHP XML parsers to do what you're looking for.